# How edit EDMX file (EF6) on .NET 7.0

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-6, dbcontext, .net-7.0, edmx

I am volunteer in a one project. We develop ASP.NET MVC Core app and we updated project to .NET 7.0. From this moment app works fine all the time, but I can't view edmx file. Is a way edit edmx without edit edmx in XML?

I tried add DbSet to DbContext, but this not work. Like i said - i can work on existing tables.

Comment: I don't think EF Core supports EDMX any more - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx

Comment: @phuzi The OP does not refer to EF Core!

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep a .NET Framework project in your solution for the .edmx file.

See my [blog post here](https://erikej.github.io/ef/dotnetcore/2020/06/15/ef6-use-edmx-dotnetcore.html)

Comment: Very thanks for your answer, but I have problem with error "
NU1201 Project <project_name> is not compatible with netcoreapp3.1 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v3.1). Project <project_name> supports: net7.0 (.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0)". When I change Framework to 7.0, errors disappears. Have you ever managed to solve this problem?